# select max on certain criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

**current table:**

```
id | type | term | sysdate | e_date | t_date  |
---+------+------+---------+--------+---------+
 3 | ugrd | 1220 | 9/10/14 | 9/1/11 | 9/15/11 |
 3 | ugrd | 1240 | 9/10/14 | 9/1/12 | 9/15/12 |
 3 | grad | 1250 | 9/10/14 | 3/6/13 | 3/20/13 |*
 3 | grad | 1380 | 9/10/14 | 9/1/14 | 9/15/14 |
```

`sysdate` = today's date (8/20 for this example)

I want to be able to query out the `max(term) where sysdate < t_date`

With this logic, this row* should be returned:

```
 3 | grad | 1250
```

Right now my sql looks a little something like this:

```
select distinct cs.id, s.type, max(cs.term)
           from tb_current_students cs 
          where sysdate < cs.t_date
```

Obviously this doesn't work, which is why I've come to you. I've tried a subquery, but that also failed. Hopefully I've provided enough information, if not comment and I shall give you more.

Answer (score 2):

Below Query using join should help you

```
SELECT A.ID, A.TYPE, A.TERM FROM
tb_current_students  A JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(TERM) MAX_TERM FROM  tb_current_students  
    WHERE TRUNC (T_DATE) < TRUNC (SYSDATE)
) B
ON A.TERM = B.MAX_TERM;
```

- [Working SQL Fiddle - 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f21e9/3) --> Returns 1380 because today's date is
  15th September
- [Working SQL Fiddle - 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/68b57/1) --> Returns 1250 because I have changed the last t_date to a
  date > 25th September.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to get rows for all dates that have passed, order then descending and just get the first row;

```
SELECT id, type, term FROM (
  SELECT * FROM tb_current_students A
  WHERE t_date < SYSDATE
  ORDER BY term DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
```

[A simple SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/06d3b/2).

Comment: This is close, but doesn't ensure we get the MAX term which is part of the requirement. I think you meant to order by term instead of t_date, then it should be good.

Comment: @MajorMajor Yes, of course, thanks. There should be a block on answering SQL questions before first coffee in the morning :)